# Do we need to replace comma in strings.xml file in Android?

Tags: android

```
<string name="text_9">This may not happen. If this happened, reset in 2&#8211;4 mins.</string>
```

I use it like this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
alertDialog.setMessage(getResources().getText(R.string.text_9));
```

The layout.xml looks like

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="15dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/explain_label"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#00000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

The displayed result is always "This may not happen. If this happened". 
Everything after comma didn't show up. I tried to replace comma with ' \ , ' and '\u002c', but neither works. If I remove the comma, everything is displayed.

How do I replace the comma to displace the full description?

Comment: Your string is fine. Are you using it in a TextView? Please post its layout xml.

Comment: So layout.xml is the dialog's custom layout? How do you use it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try to set the message before calling the `create()` method:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setMessage(R.string.text_9)
.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Or replace the `getResources().getText(R.string.text_9)` method with `getString(R.string.text_9)`.